# How to activate tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath in 2 sections?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have one UItableView divided in 2 sections.

How I can manage the method tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

For the section 1 the method is running but for I don't know how to implement to the 2nd section.

Thanks

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 if(indexPath.section == 0) {
   //Your code for Section 1 with the index 0
 } else {
   //Your code for Section 2 with the index 1
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the delegate method of UITableView :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

And you can differentiate within section using the below code :

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) 
if (indexPath.section == 1)

..upto n depends on number of sections in your TableView.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 if(indexPath.section == 0){
  if(indexpath.row == 0){
  //Your code here
  }
 }
 else if(indexPath.section == 0){
  if(indexpath.row == 0){
  //Your code here
  }
 }
}
```